# How to correctly add an external script to a ReactJS component in Gatsby.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I am trying to add a Trustpilot widget to my Gatsby.js website. To make the Widget styling work, it is required to load an external script from Trustpilot CDN.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
```

I have tried multiple ways to add this script to my footer component. The first thing I tried was React Helmet. I added using the following code:

```
<Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
</Helmet>
```

The script seems to load and the styling works when I initially load a page. Once I navigate to a different page, the styling goes away. As I reload, it comes back.

I then tried adding the script inside componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    var addScript = document.createElement('script');
    addScript.setAttribute('src', '//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(addScript);
}
```

But even that yields the same result.

What's going on here? Is the external js script going away? How can I load it correctly so that it stays?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you navigate away the parent component is being unmounted and Helmet removes the corresponding `script` tag from the `head`. To avoid this, place the component above the page component, e.g. using [`wrapPageElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/#wrapPageElement) or [`wrapRootElement`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/#wrapRootElement) as needed.
2. Naive scripts that inject code into the DOM are going to be problematic. [React has some notes and tips on this in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html). Typically I will search to see if the vendor has any documentation on integrating with a single-page app. If not, you might need to do some code spelunking to figure out how to best support the desired functionality within the constraints.

Comment: `wrapPageElement` wraps the page element inside another html element if I am understanding it correcting. Like wrapping pages inside a layout. My problem here is a bit different since I need to add a script, so I don't know what to wrap and into what.

Comment: `wrapPageElement` wraps in a React component, which can be a React element (i.e. HTML element) or a custom component. You probably want the latter, and you can either return an array with your script and the `element` prop, or you can use a React Fragment to wrap both.